# How to select specific columns in r using regex

Tags: r, regex, dplyr

Due to the poor regex knowledge, I don't know how to select specific columns in r using regex.

There is a short example. I have a dataframe `df` that have lots of variables.

```
a = c('1.age41_50', '2.age51_60', '3.age61_70', '4.age71_80',
      '5.age1_20', '6.age21_30', '7.age31_40', '8.ageupwith65', '9.agelo65', '10.PM2_5')

df = matrix(ncol = 10, nrow = 1) %>% as_tibble()
colnames(df) = a
df
```

I want to select specific variables using `select()` and `matches()` from `dplyr` package.
Regex should follow the following conditions:

> variable names should not contain `age` and `_` in the meantime.

In my view, I first search variable names that contain `age` and `_` in the meantime and then reverse select it but failed. Such as this:

```
df %>% select(!matches('age&_'))
```

The final result should like this:

```
df_expected = df %>% select(`8.ageupwith65`, `9.agelo65`, `10.PM2_5`)
```

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```r
> df %>% select(!matches('age[0-9]+_')) 
# A tibble: 1 x 3
  `8.ageupwith65` `9.agelo65` `10.PM2_5`
  <lgl>           <lgl>       <lgl>     
1 NA              NA          NA
```

This expression matches `age`, one or more digits, and then an underscore. The final result is reversed due to the `!` operator.

Answer (score 1):

We may use

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   select(-contains('age'), matches('age(?!.*_)', perl = TRUE))
# A tibble: 1 × 3
  `10.PM2_5` `8.ageupwith65` `9.agelo65`
  <lgl>      <lgl>           <lgl>      
1 NA         NA              NA
```